# Reverse array in place... what's wrong with my implementation

Tags: javascript, reverse

I was trying to reverse an array in-place like for example given an array `[1, 2, 3]` reverse it to `[3, 2, 1]`.

Here's my implementation for it:

```
function reverseInPlace(arr) {
    var start = 0;
    var end = arr.length + 1;
    
    while (start > end) {
        var temp = arr[start];
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = temp;
    }
    
    return arr;
};

reverseInPlace([1,2,3])
```

But every time I ran this, the result is still in `[1, 2, 3]`, not `[3, 2, 1]`. I want to know what am I doing wrong with my reverse.

Comment: Because this is never true: `while (start > end) {`. Start is 0, end is 4 and 0 isnt more than 4

Comment: Please note: There isnt a `++` anywhere, so if you simple reverse the condition, you have created an endless loop :)

Comment: Just use push and pop function it is much more simpler then your function you can check in my answer

Comment: `var end = arr.length - 1;` `-`.
`while (start < end)` `<` + in `{` `start++; end--;`.

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues:

- wrong `end` value, it should be the last index which is `length - 1`,
- while check is wrong, you need to check `start < end`, the original code is at start `false`, that is the reason to get an unchanged array,
- missing increment of `start` and decrement of `end`.

```js
function reverseInPlace(arr) {
    let start = 0,
        end = arr.length - 1;

    while (start < end) {
        let temp = arr[start];
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = temp;

        start++;
        end--;    
    }

    return arr;
}

console.log(reverseInPlace([1, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your while loop never gets executed. Since you've initiated var start = 0, and end = arr.length. Inside the while loop, both start and end should be updated as well.

```js
function reverseInPlace(arr) {
    var start = 0;
    var end = arr.length-1;
    
    while (start < end) {
        var temp = arr[start];
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = temp;
        end--;
        start++;
    }
    
    return arr;
};

console.log(reverseInPlace([1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `start` is smaller than `end`, `while (start > end)` loop will never run, also you need to update `start` and `end` to swap next pair of numbers:

```js
function reverseInPlace(arr) {
    var start = 0;
    var end = arr.length - 1;
    
    while (start < end) {
        var temp = arr[start];
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
    
    return arr;
};

var res = reverseInPlace([1,2,3])

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is simple way you can use pop and push js function for that

```
function reverseInPlace(arr) {
    var start = 0;
    var end = arr.length;
    var new_arr = [];
    for(var i = 1; i <= end; i++){
       new_arr.push(arr.pop());
    }
    
    return new_arr;
};

reverseInPlace([1,2,3])
```